# Loop while mouse hover is in element JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need animation while mousehover is in element, but when user make mouseout element the animation stop in local current.

```js
        countRotate = 0;
        adiciona = true;
        $('.circulo-left').mouseenter(function(){
            $('#circuloprincipalcomabaazulclaro').css('transform', 'rotate('+countRotate+'deg)');
            if(adiciona == true){
                countRotate++;
                if(countRotate == 360){
                    adiciona = false;
                }
            }else{
                countRotate = countRotate - 1;
                 if(countRotate == 0){
                    adiciona = true;
                }
            }
        });
        // I thought of something like that.
```

```css
.circle{
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      border-radius:50%;
      border
    }
    .circle:hover{
        #circuloprincipalcomabaazulclaro{
            @include animation(rotate 3s infinite alternate);
        }
    }
    @keyframes rotate {
        from{
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to{
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    /* But when I remove the mouse it returns to the starting point. */
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: We are good, thanks for asking. Please share what you have tried and read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: We need [mcve] more than anything.

Comment: The code snippet does not work. You need to include jquery.

Comment: Where `#circuloprincipalcomabaazulclaro` coming from?

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE: Added some JS to get the desired output.**

You dont need jquery or js to get this effect. Here is what you need to do.

***Edited your code a bit.***

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');

circle.onmouseover = function(){
  this.style.animation = 'rotate 1.5s infinite linear';  
  this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState="running";
}

circle.onmouseout = function(){
    this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState="paused";
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  width: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: made it a square because it is not possible to see the rotation of a full circle.

Comment: This is equal my code.
However this way, when the user removes the mouse it returns to the starting position.

Comment: @Wellingtonfjr, check now :)

Answer (score 1):

I've built on @hunzaboy 's answer, the OP stated he wants the animation to maintain it's state so I've made a few adjustments, also made the spin linear.

the spin will stay were you left it for 999999999 seconds (about 277 hours)

```css
.circle{
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      border-radius:50%;
      background: red;
      position: relative;
      transition-property: transform;
      transition-duration: 2s;
      transition-delay: 999999999s;
      transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
span{
  width: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  }
    .circle:hover{
       transform: rotate(360deg);
       transition-delay: 0s;
    }
    /* But when I remove the mouse it returns to the starting point. */
```

```html
<div class="circle"><span></span></div>
```

Comment: @Jamesonthedog, it only runs for once. Check my updated answer :)